# Stop Automatic MMS Resizing in Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, mms

**How do I stop Twilio from automatically resizing my Gifs in an MMS Media Message?**

I'm looking to send a MMS message in Twilio with 3 separate Gifs, but Twilio automatically resizes the Gifs. Unfortunately, this makes the message look hideous as there are 3 Gifs of differing size.

The format is as follows:

*Introductory Text*

Gif 1

Gif 2

Gif 3

Answer (score 0):

See if setting the maximum size to 600KB.

[Will Twilio automatically resize my images for MMS messaging?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133547-Will-Twilio-automatically-resize-my-images-for-MMS-messaging-)

> "If you prefer to resize your own images, we recommend that images be
> no larger than 600KB."

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for the help! Would you happen to know how to resize the image yourself? I'm very new to coding (less than 10 hours of experience) so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm using python.

Comment: Don't really have an answer for you there, specific to resizing GIF images with Python.